# What's the interleaved audio ?

Tags: ios, audio, core-audio

i see this interleaved audio many times on core audio documents.Can someone explain me what's really functionality of this property.

Comment: why don't you look into Google ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Generally speaking, if you have 2 channels, let's call them L for left and R for right, and you want to transmit or store 20 samples, then:

Interleaved = LRLRLRLRLRLRLRLRLRLR

Non-Interleaved = LLLLLLLLLLRRRRRRRRR

Comment: good answer, although non-interleaved generally means that you would actually have two buffers for your example, one containing only left samples, and one containing only right samples.